# Why is UnityWebRequest so slow in Unity 2020.3.19f1

Tags: unity-game-engine, get, unitywebrequest

I just upgraded my project from Unity 2017 to 2020.3.19f1 version, however I found that our UnityWebRequest response time became so long. Here is my test using UnityWebRequest to Get [www.yahoo.com](http://www.yahoo.com) built by an empty project within Unity 2017 and 2020.3.19. Does anyone also encounter this problem ? Here is

Picture of response time(in ms) showing difference between the two versions.

[image]

Comment: in general your request says it failed all the time? Probably 2020 just tries more things in resolving the URL maybe?

Comment: @derHugo Sorry for making this easily misunderstanding. The "failed" is just a testing string. I am simply testing the response time.

Comment: Thanks for the reply btw. :)

Comment: are you specifying http or https for this? If not specifying, could it be that the more recent version assumes https and the earlier one assumes http? How do the times compare if you specify http vs specify https?